# NUnit tests fail because of DLL loading issue within F# library

Tags: f#, nunit, assembly-binding-redirect

I've ran into this issue before when using NUnit with F#:

> Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.6.3.13283

I have downgraded my version of FSharp.Core to a lower version number.
I'm not sure what I need to do to get my tests to run without any exceptions.

**Code**

```
module Foo

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

[<Test>]
let ``some test``() =
    1 |> should equal 1
```

**Packages.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FSharp.Core" version="4.0.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="FsUnit" version="1.4.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="NUnitTestAdapter" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.assert" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.extensibility.execution" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using NUnit 2.x instead of 3.x? I switched a few months ago to 3.x and now that I have adjusted to the changes am pleased.

Comment: It doesn't show up in test explorer.

Comment: I am able to use NUnit 3.x with VS 2015 Community / Test Explorer. I do have [NUnit3 Test Adapter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d) installed. Maybe you should ask a new SO question. I don't know the answer if you did install the NUnit3 Test Adapter. Note: There are different NUnit Test Adapters. One for 2.x and one for 3.x

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is most likely because `FsUnit` references an older version of `nunit.framework` (2.6.3), but your applcation is compiled against a newer version of NUnit (2.6.4).

The way to solve this is to add `app.config` to your test project, which will map all versions of NUnit to the one that you are referencing in your project. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework"  
             publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9999.9999.9999.9999" 
             newVersion="2.6.4.14350" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I was solving the exact same problem in [one project recently](https://github.com/ionide/FsInteractiveService/blob/master/tests/FsInteractiveService.Tests/App.config), so the above might just work for you - but if no, check what is your version of `nunit.framework.dll` using a tool like ILSpy. I have 2.6.4.14350, but you might have a different one.

Comment: I had to also lower the version of FSharp.Core to 3.1.25